# trying to get a passive AM bar antenna to work

Tags: antenna, am, ferrite

I pulled a nice big external AM ferrite bar antenna off a working stereo. 5.5" long.

it has 4 wires coming off of it. red must be the main wire, because checking that with an LCR meter connected to the other wires I get (uH)
blue, 310
black, 310
white, 372

so I connect the red and white wires to an air gap variable capacitor gang. 125, 250, and 250 pF. I can use any combination.

I put the antenna on a radio, right along where I know its ferrite bar antenna is.

the only thing that happens is when the VC is about midrange the signal gets nulled. not sharp at all, there is a wide range of VC that makes it happen.

it's not the wrong antenna orientation, because I had already chosen a weak signal with the radio oriented to pick it up.

why is it degrading reception instead of improving it?

Comment: Welcome! How do you connect the radio to the antenna? Is C in parallel with the antenna, or series? You know L, have you calculated the resonant frequency you expect from L&C?  You can edit your question to add detail, or even a circuit diagram.

Comment: Null?  You do know these are directional, right?  Did you find a null by changing antenna orientation rather than by changing the VC?